# Is there a way to prevent all actions while css transition takes place?

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I am trying to disable every action until a transition that is triggered manually is finished.

I am using this simple code:

```
myelem.click(function() {
   myotherelem.addClass('transition');
};
```

and then...

```
myelem.on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', function() {
   // I am done!
});
```

What I am looking for is for a way to disable all activity, either click, touch, anything at all until the animation finishes. Any ideas?

Comment: Register a handler for the actions you want to disable to in your click callback that prevents the default action and doesn't propagate. If this doesn't work create a boolean flag that is checked in your callbacks and set in your click and animation callback.

Comment: Yes, you will have to handle every event manually, there is no magic command that will block all user activity. Also, this is not my business, but I think this is terrible from the UX point of view.

Comment: ..I can't see how this is terrible for someone to can't click anywhere for 0.3 secs. Would it be better to hit on the 'close' button and have the animation play in reverse as soon as it's done?

Comment: You can try to set : body {pointer-events:none;} . brutal, if browser understand this, there's no way to click anything inside body. no idea if it includes touchevents ... just a comment :)

Answer (score 2):

If by "all actions triggered manually" you mean click's, then applying "pointer-events: none" to all painted elements should to the job.

JS:

```
myelem.click(function() {
    myotherelem.addClass('transition');
    body.addClass('freeze');
};

myelem.on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', function() {
    // I am done!
    body.removeClass('freeze')
});
```

CSS:

```
.freeze {
   pointer-events:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dropdownMenusUl.on('transitionstart', function() {
        jQuery(this).css('pointer-events', 'none');
});

dropdownMenusUl.on('transitionend', function() {
        jQuery(this).css('pointer-events', 'all');
});
```

Comment: Consider editing your answer to include descriptive text as to how the specified code answers the question.